# Turn a list of string to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of strings like this:

```
l = ['ABC, Apple, 20021015, 20030102', 'CDE, Graps, 20020506, 20030130']
```

I want to convert this list to a dictionary like

```
d = { 'ABC': 'Apple', 'CDE': 'Graps' }
```

So the key would be the first name in the string and the value would be the second name in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in Python 2:

```
d = {j[0]:j[1] for j in [i.split(', ') for i in l]}
```

Output:

```
{'CDE': 'Graps', 'ABC': 'Apple'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
for index in range(len(l)):
    line = l[index].split(", ")
    d[line[0]] = line[1]
```

So, you split each entry by commas to get each name and date individually, and then you can add them each to the dict as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, shorter form:

```
>>> dict(x.split(', ')[:2] for x in l)
{'ABC': 'Apple', 'CDE': 'Graps'}
```

This works by passing a sequence of two-element lists to `dict()` which then initializes the dictionary based on that sequence. The sequence being passed is this:

```
>>> [x.split(', ')[:2] for x in l]
[['ABC', 'Apple'], ['CDE', 'Graps']]
```